# WinUI 3 and legacy DirectX9 Component

Tags: c#, directx, directx-9, winui-3

We are currently using Windows Forms and a C# Direct3D9 component for rendering that uses SlimDX.

What options are there to use the existing D3D9 code in WinUI 3? So far, it is not looking good.

It appears that we have to rewrite the component in C++/D3D11. Hopefully I am missing something.

Comment: You will have to port your DirectX9 code to DirectX11, but C++ is not mandatory. You can do that with C#, there are various interop projects out there (although none is "official" sanctified) they are more or less listed here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incorporate-directx-into-the-windows-runtime/393776 also https://github.com/terrafx/terrafx. I can personnaly speak for this one I wrote myself: https://github.com/smourier/DirectN

Comment: Thank you very much for those links. This means you can use SurfaceImageSource from C#, just like Microsoft suggests? You don't happen to have an example for that?

Comment: WinUI3 (and WinRT) is fully usable from C# but there's nothing built-in for raw COM types outside of these (like ISurfaceImageSourceNative for example https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/blob/master/DirectN/DirectN/Generated/ISurfaceImageSourceNative.cs). This article is still valid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh825871(v=win.10) (replace Windows.UI.Xaml by Microsoft.UI.Xaml in the case of WinUI3). I forgot to mention Win2D for WinUI3 https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/Introduction.htm which is a work in progress (hopefully)